# form isn't submitting with attributes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am creating forms dynamically for each store.

This is my code.

```
<form action="/{{$stores[$i]}}/order/place" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      @foreach($products as $product)
      <?php $details = getProductById($product['product']); ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="td_name">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
            <a href="/{{$stores[$i]}}/product/{{$details->slug}}"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-11">
            <input value="{{ $details->product_name }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td_qty">
        <div class="">
          <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td_price">
        <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. {{price_check($details->product_discount, $details->product_price, $details->sale_id, $details->discount, $details->sale_status)}} /-" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
<tfooter>
  <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order" />
</tfooter>
</table>
```

Now from the result from this code I am getting is this

```
<form action="/ali_store/order/place" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="CJDqNipNtpNavJ9m1fogtUyCThJe2GCS75bI6KJ2">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-hover">
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td class="td_name">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="/ali_store/product/Abc-ali_store_updated-ali-rasheed-ka-pehla-product"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
          <input value="Ali Rasheed ka pehla product" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_qty">
      <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_price">
      <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. 63,708 /-" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="td_name">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="/ali_store/product/"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
          <input value="Ali Rasheed" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_qty">
      <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_price">
      <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. 109,579 /-" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="td_name">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="/ali_store/product/Abc123ali_store_updatedabc-gtx-1070"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
          <input value="Abc GTX 1070" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_qty">
      <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_price">
      <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. 900 /-" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="td_name">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="/ali_store/product/"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
          <input value="asdasd asd" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_qty">
      <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_price">
      <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. 10,958 /-" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="td_name">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <a href="/ali_store/product/asdasdasd-ali_store_updated-asdasdasda"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
          <input value="Newest tesing product" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_qty">
      <div class="">
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td_price">
      <input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control" disabled value="Rs. 1,000 /-" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
<tfooter>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order" />
</tfooter>
 </table>
```

When I submit this form to controller to check

```
dd($request->name);
```

I get no attributes. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `disabled` in input fields

use this with `disabled` remove and it will show you the price

```
<input type="price[]" name="price[]" class="form-control"value="Rs. {{price_check($details->product_discount, $details->product_price, $details->sale_id, $details->discount, $details->sale_status)}} /-" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` form field contains the `disabled` attribute.

```
<input value="Ali Rasheed" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" disabled/>
```

Just remove `disabled` and then it should be properly available in `$request`.

You may be looking for the `readonly` attribute instead.